# "Планер" или "планёр"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, фонетика

Так все-таки, как правильно: плАнер или *планёр*? Чаще первое употребляется для обозначения безмоторного самолета, а второе - о том, кто планирует (не летит в потоках воздуха, а составляет планы). Кстати, почему два таких разных дела обозначены одним словом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Планируют действительно планеристы, планировщики и планёры/планеры. Но последние - летательные аппараты, никак не люди.
Смещение уларения в планёре, исходно слове французском, произошло, видимо, под воздействим английского.
Что касается "разных понятий", то тут ничего удивительного. Планировать (строить планы)  - от того же английского to plan - очень многозначного английского глагола.

Answer (score 1):

Безмоторный летательный аппарат - планёр (и планер). А вот чтобы человека, который что-то там планирует, называли планёром, первый раз слышу :-)

Answer (score 0):

Планёр - профессиональный жаргон, относится не только к планеру как целому аппарату, но и к части самолета.
Планер - бытовое название типа летательного устройства.

Comment: Точно не знаю, но по-моему наоборот =)